# Why can I access private data members through pointers and should I do this?

Tags: c++, pointers, private, member, access-modifiers

I just discovered that I can do this in C++, which compiles just fine (MinGW and VC++):

```
class A
{
private:
   void doSth();
   A* foo;
   A* bar;
};

void A::doSth()
{
  foo->bar;
}
```

The member field `bar` of `foo` is private. **Why can I access it and should I do so?**

Comment: Please post proof of its privacy.

Comment: @Ben What do you mean? `bar` is under `private`.

Comment: If private variables were totally inaccessible, that wouldn't be very useful now would it..:)

Comment: If it was illegal, you would not be able to do anything with private members.

Comment: But `bar` is in another instance (`foo`) since I do `foo->bar`.

Comment: Why would you name them both bar? Why is your name foo bar? Do you realise there are other identifiers you can use?

Comment: +1. It's a good question because I can see how pointers would confuse what's going on with visibility.

Comment: @Ben Maybe OP likes the [player](http://www.foobar2000.org/). What does it matter? Gee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, `private` means the access is limited to the same class, not to the same object instance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this as soon as I can. I was not aware that access modifiers are class-based. Thought they were instance-based.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also notice that in A's methods, other instances of A's private variables may be access. Like

```
A::baz(A& other) {
    other.bar; // legal
}
```

Visibility is at the class level, not instance level.

Comment: Why did you add another answer instead of editing the 1st one?

Comment: @luk32 because the first was wrong and this is different. I didn't understand the question properly.

Comment: So ... why not edit the wrong one? Maybe I didn't see the pending deletion. It was awkward.

Comment: @djechlin Would editing the first answer you posted to the correct answer not help?

Comment: @luk32 because I think it's stupid to transmogrify one answer into a completely different one. The votes become meaningless, for one thing. Maybe whoever really liked my blatantly wrong answer won't like my correct one.

Comment: @luk32 plus it's a wrong answer. it needs to be deleted ASAP. Because it's wrong. Takes longer to write a correct answer than delete an incorrect one.

Comment: Yea, ok, I just saw two different, and up-voted answers at the same time. It was weird. It was so fast, I don't think anyone would notice. Nevermind.